# Convert datetime to specific format including zone - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strptime

I have the date in the following format

```
Thu, 07 Nov 2019 20:25:00 UTC +00:00
```

I need to display it as `7 November 2019, 14:25:00 GMT-6`. I have tried

```
date.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

which produces the output `"07 Nov 2019 20:25:00 +00:00"`

I need to display with the timezone as GMT-6

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_time_zone(offset)` to achieve that.
Like below:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(-6).strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT-6')
=> "12 Jun 2020 12:12:51 GMT-6"
```